# How to modify activation email content in Open edX Platform?

Tags: edx, openedx

Someone has previously asked a question regarding the location of the activation email .txt file for the profile activation email that is sent out when a user registers on an Open edX platform.

I have located these files and made changes. Further, I have manually compiled the assets and restarted the lms, cms, and workers. My problem is that the old email is still sent when a user registers on the platform.

Can anyone help me understand what I need to do to make these changes happen? I've been working on this for a while and, to me, this seems like a straight forward problem. But I don't really understand what is happening, so am having trouble getting the desired output.

Comment: Please point out the path of the files that you have modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With latest platform release you just need to change the content in following files:

1. lms/templates/emails/activation_email_subject.txt
2. lms/templates/emails/activation_email.txt

Nothing else needed, tested locally.

Comment: This is correct. What had actually happened is that I was using comprehensive theming, and this was overwriting the changes to the email templates that I was making. Essentially, to make this work I restored any changes to the original templates in the edx source, and simply implemented my changes in the theming profile. I feel a bit silly for not recognising this sooner.

Answer (score 1):

Text activation emails are mako templates and they get compiled in a temporary location. The server is most likely not compiling them again after your modifications.

Try to clean the `/tmp/mako_lms/<some_hash>/emails/` directory.

You can even remove everything in `/tmp/mako_lms` if you don't care about the penalty of mako recompiling everything again.

One liner:

```
sudo rm /tmp/mako_lms/*/emails/*
```